# Laravel raw expression is not working when including wildcard parameter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Given the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%?%'";
$key = 'orange';
$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw($sql), [$key]);
```

the result is always no records!

while by changing `LIKE` to `=`, it works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = ?";
```

I don't know why this is happening but I **have** to use *RAW* in this script. Can anybody figure out where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You're failing to understand how bindings work... binding not only handles quotes and other special characters within the value, but also handles the quoting

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE ?";
$key = '%orange%';
$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw($sql), [$key]);
```

and note the `%` around the `$key` value before you bind it

Comment: And in this case you don't need to use `DB::raw` inside `DB::select`. The latter already has the ability to run raw sql, so you can just do: `DB::select($sql, [$key]);`